# Set margin top for a DIV using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the situation, i have a fixed header with 120px height, and i forced the page to jump to #testdiv when the query string is #testdiv.

But the issue is when page jumps to beginning of the above DIV, part of the content will be lost,because it's behind the fixed header, is there any jquery to force page to jump to the #testdiv with not actual margin?

I tried the below code but it makes actual margin

```
if (url.indexOf('#testdiv') >= 0) {
$('#testdiv').css('margin-top',120);
};
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think there would be easiest way to do that, set `margin-top` for your field, and set the negative `margin-top` for your parent field.

It should be work for you.

```
if (url.indexOf('#testdiv') >= 0) {
$('#testdiv').css('margin-top',120);
$('#parent').css('margin-top',"-120px");
};
```

Comment: This helped me because I was missing the 'px' off my negative value

Answer (score 10):

You can set margin-top via jQuery like this:

```
$("#mydiv").css("margin-top", "10px");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a fixed header which you don't want to overlap content you need to add `padding-top` to the containing div (or the body if required) which matches the height of the fixed content to push the underlying elements down.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but basically in this specific case, i want to have overlap image under the header.